# What is the meaning of ~ before (l, r)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

I read the library of Haskell

```
partitionEithers :: [Either a b] -> ([a],[b])
partitionEithers = foldr (either left right) ([],[])
 where
  left  a ~(l, r) = (a:l, r)
  right a ~(l, r) = (l, a:r)
```

What is the meaning of `~` before `(l, r)`?

Comment: You can think of `left a ~(l, r) = (a:l, r)` as `left a pair = (a:fst pair, snd pair)`. I think they are completely equivalent but I'm not 100%

Comment: @Iceland_jack, they are not quite equivalent.  `fst pair` is outfitted with a special rig to rewrite `snd pair` to `r` (and vice versa), so as to destroy the reference to `pair` and improve degenerate GC behavior.

Comment: @luqui, that should apply to the lazy pattern match as well. `left` will compile to something like `left a lr = (a : case lr of (l,_) -> l, case lr of (_, r) -> r)`. Those cases will both become "selector thunks", treated specially by the GC.

Comment: @dfeuer, wait I'm confused. I didn't mean to say that if `fst`/`snd` are written literally this will happen -- in fact I think it won't.  I mean as the lazy pattern is "translated" (conceptually) they become special versions of `fst`/`snd` which do this special thing. Are we on the same page?

Comment: @luqui, not so sure.... `fst` and `snd` will generally inline to do the right thing there. I also don't think your description of the rig is how it works. The `fst lr` (once inlined) doesn't compile (ultimately) to "create a thunk to apply the `fst` function to `lr`." It compiles to "create a *selector thunk* that chooses the first component of `lr`." When the garbage collector sees a selector thunk, it checks whether the argument is in WHNF and, if so, reduces it to the appropriate component. Now I know there was a later paper that suggested a (possibly more robust?) way that *doesn't* rely

Comment: on GC, but last I heard this is how GHC does it.

Comment: @dfeuer, ah, thanks, nice to know about the fiddlies.

Comment: A list of hard to search symbols can be found at [Haskell/GHC symbol search cheatsheet](https://github.com/takenobu-hs/haskell-symbol-search-cheatsheet).

Comment: @dfeuer @luqui Testing with `testL f ~(x, y) = f x y; testF f xy = f (fst xy) (snd xy); testI f xy = f (inline fst xy) (inline snd xy)`, I observe: in `testF`, `fst` and `snd` do not inline and "do the right thing"; GHC doesn't seem to notice the benefit. Forcing it in `testI` works, causing deduplication to `testI = testL`. `testF`'s thunks are really just normal thunks with code in them. Meanwhile `testL` actually uses on built-in, static selector thunks pre-specialized in the RTS, which seems to make it "much better" than `testF`.

Comment: @HTNW, they don't even inline with optimization on? That's rather sad. I think I'll open a ticket.

Comment: @dfeuer Yep, I tested it with `-O2` and they just sit there. Uninlined. I was surprised too. Do be warned though, I did this on 8.6.5. Maybe 8.8 is better about this.

Comment: @HTNW, doubt it, but worth a check.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a [lazy pattern match](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Lazy_pattern_matching).  It means that the pattern match is assumed to be successful, and only actually performed when its data is needed.

```
ghci> strictPat (a,b) = "hello"
ghci> lazyPat  ~(a,b) = "hello"

ghci> strictPat undefined
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> lazyPat undefined
"hello"

ghci> strictPat2 (a,b) = "the values are " ++ a ++ " and " ++ b
ghci> lazyPat2  ~(a,b) = "the values are " ++ a ++ " and " ++ b

ghci> strictPat2 undefined
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> lazyPat2 undefined
"the values are *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

It is used here so that `partitionEithers` can be a good streamer.  Otherwise it would have to evaluate the whole list before it could return the first element of either of its results (because e.g. `left` would force the incoming pair, which was generated by a recursive call, which would have to force its incoming pair, and so on...).

Comment: Wow I always knew Haskell was non-strict but this is on a whole other level than what I previously expected. Seeing "the values are" being printed immediately before the Exception is awesome.

Comment: @EnricoBorba, you like that?  Here's a favorite:  `howToWrite = "How to write this book: " ++ concatMap (\x -> "write " ++ show x ++ ", then ") (words 
howToWrite)`.